# Rails undefined method `hospital' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model-view-controller, exception

Respected ppl ...

In my application i want to display the last hospital name for a given employee ...

for which i tried this :

```
<%= @employee.postings.last.hospital.hospital_name %>
```

All the required associations are correct ...as this works perfectly for all the employees who have a posting ... but i get the error for the employees who dont have even a single posting ...

I tried doing

```
<%= @employee.postings.last.hospital.hospital_name.to_s %>
```

and even

```
<% if !@employee.postings.last.hospital.nil? %>
```

and even a "try" function ....

I just want it to not display any data when there dosent exist one ... instead of the intimidating error ...

if i could just learn how to skip over printing nil values then it would be awesome ..as i am facing similar issues elsewhere too ...

For ex : 
in my employees main page i want to display all the qualifications for each employee for which im doing :

```
<tbody>
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= employee.emp_id %></td>
    <td><%= employee.emp_treasury_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to employee.emp_full_name,employee_path(employee) %></td>
    <% @employee.qualifications.each do |qualification| %>
            <td><%= qualification.qualification_name.Qualification_name %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

but i end up getting "undefined method `qualifications' for nil:NilClass" error once again ...
Im trying a lot ... but still ...

Thanx and Sincere Regards

-Sky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= @employee.postings.last.try(:hospital).try(:hospital_name) || "N/A" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

using `try`

```
<%= @employee.postings.last.try(:hospital).try(:hospital_name) %>
```

using `if`

```
<%= @employee.postings.last.hospital.hospital_name if @employee.postings.exists? && @employee.positings.last.hospital %>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

> employee not @employee

Rest you use try or respond_to for being more safe. As you might not have run the migrations.

```
.respond_to?(:field) && model.try(:field)
```

Thanks

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= employee.emp_id %></td>
    <td><%= employee.emp_treasury_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to employee.emp_full_name,employee_path(employee) %></td>
    <% employee.qualifications.each do |qualification| %>
            <td><%= qualification.try(:qualification_name).try(:Qualification_name) %></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```